# Need help to print scrabble board!

Tags: java

```
public class Project1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //ScrabbleLetterBag letterBag = new ScrabbleLetterBag();
        char [][] scrabbleBoard = new char [15][15];

        for (int i = 0; i <=scrabbleBoard.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print(i - 1);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <=scrabbleBoard.length; j++) {
                if (j == 8 && i == 8) {
                    scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '*';
                    System.out.print(scrabbleBoard[i][j]);  
                }
                else {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.out.print(" "+j);
                    }
                    else{
                        scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '_';
                        System.out.print(" ");
                        System.out.print(scrabbleBoard[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /*int count = 0;
    char myLetter;
    while (!letterBag.isEmpty()) {
        count++;
        myLetter = letterBag.getLetter();
        System.out.print(myLetter);
        if (count % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }*/

}
```

It should print out something like

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 

 0  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 1  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 2  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 3  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 4  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 5  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 6  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 7  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 8  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
 9  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
10  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
11  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
12  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
13  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
14  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
```

For some reason my code is not working help me to fix it plz

Comment: What is not working?  Does it compile?  Does anything print?

Comment: you don't show '*' anywhere in your intended output, but it's there in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I think it generates better output:

```
public class Project1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //ScrabbleLetterBag letterBag = new ScrabbleLetterBag();
        char [][] scrabbleBoard = new char [16][16];

        for (int i = 0; i<scrabbleBoard.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println("\t");
                System.out.print(i-1);
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <scrabbleBoard.length; j++) {
                if (j == 8 && i == 8) {
                    scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '*';
                    System.out.print(scrabbleBoard[i][j]);  
                }
                else {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.out.print("\t");
                        System.out.print(j-1);
                    }
                    else {
                        scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '_';
                        System.out.print("\t");
                        System.out.print(""+scrabbleBoard[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simplify your problem by printing a 3x3 board first?

At that point, your code will be small enough that you can go through each iteration one at a time and understand where your code behaves differently than what you want.  You can follow where you are in your code either my adding more print statements or stepping through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to break some of this into separate `for` loops so you've got a better handle on what's going on.  Print your numbers across the top in a separate loop before you get into printing the whole grid.  Renaming `i` and `j` to `row` and `column` might help you too.

Right now, you're iterating over `i` from `0` to `14`, and printing `i - 1`, which would give you rows numbered `-1` to `13`.  But then you're not printing anything when `i == 0`, which is why you're getting row numbers `0` to `13` but no `14`.  As you get further along you'll also realize you want the code that assigns the initial blanks to the board to be separate from the code that prints the board out, otherwise you'll be overwriting any letters that are added.

---

Update:

I think going `<` was the right approach, but this is the first change I'd make:

```
System.out.print("   "); // indent so there's room for row numbers
for (int col = 0; col < scrabbleBoard.length; col++) {
    // give single digit numbers extra padding to keep them aligned
    if (col < 10)
        System.out.print("  " + col); 
    else
        System.out.print(" " + col);
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < scrabbleBoard.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i - 1);

    for (int j = 0; j < scrabbleBoard.length; j++) {
        if (j == 8 && i == 8) {
            scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '*';
            System.out.print(scrabbleBoard[i][j]);  
        }
        else {
            scrabbleBoard[i][j] = '_';
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(scrabbleBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that printing the column headers separately makes the main loop quite a bit simpler.  I gave you a start on getting things aligned in the column header, you'll have to do something similar in the main loop to keep things lined up.

Comment: I edited my program , now both for loops are <= , cuz i want the first line and first row to be number count starts from 0, but its not not working .